# ¿Alguna forma de visualizar archivos .msg en el navegador?

Tags: html, html5, msg

Tengo diferentes archivos **.msg** en mi servidor y otros archivos (**.docx**, **.mp3**, **.jpg** ... etc), ¿hay alguna forma de previsualizar los archivos **.msg** en el navegador? Algo similar a la vista previa de documentos de office con google viewer.

Ejemplo:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.snee.com/xml/xslt/sample.doc&embedded=true" style="width:500px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Quisiera poder hacer algo así:

```
<iframe src="http://ejemplourl.com/ejemploemail.msg" style="width:500px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Gracias.

[Esta página](https://www.encryptomatic.com/viewer/) puede mostrar este tipo de archivos, yo quisiera hacer algo similar.

Mi web la tengo para funcione en los principales, Chrome, Firefox, Opera y Safari únicamente, versiones mínimas, 51, 49, 38 y 11 respectivamente. Pero desde que se pueda hacer que funcione en [chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome) y [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox), sería perfecto para mí.

---

> [Misma pregunta en el foro inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113682/any-way-to-preview-msg-files-in-navigator).

Comment: [Aquí](https://github.com/ykarpovich/msg.reader) hay una librería que acabo de encontrar.

Comment: La ví, pero no es buena, no muestra correctamente los correos como son enviados.

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir un ejemplo de archivo `.msg`?

Comment: Claro, me disculpo la demora en responder, este es el archivo ejemplo que intento visualizar, es un correo de Google https://mega.nz/#!XgoGGQQB!qkEkKlDCeqPwXLScfZ2jT2tfUSx0Hpa_mQ2l_ESpLYg

Comment: Sigue estando algo amplia tu pregunta, ¿podrías especificar para qué versiones de navegadores esperas que funcione?

Comment: Por supuesto, mi web la tengo para funcione en los principales, Chrome, Firefox, Opera y Safari únicamente, versiones mínimas, 51, 49, 38 y 11 respectivamente. Pero desde que se pueda hacer que funcione en Chrome y Firefox, sería perfecto para mí.

Answer (score 1):

Depende mucho de los navegadores en unos no funciona,  pero yo he usado esta forma:

```
<object data="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.snee.com/xml/xslt/sample.doc&embedded=true"  width="500" height="500" />
```

Comment: Solo coloco en data la URL del archivo .msg?

Comment: Intenté colocarlo y lo que hace es intentar descargar el archivo, el data al parecer no me sirve para eso jaja

Comment: Hay una página que puede mostrar este tipo de archivos, yo quisiera poder hacer algo similar, mira https://www.encryptomatic.com/viewer/

Comment: Revisando la url https://www.encryptomatic.com/viewer/ ese sitio primero convierte el archivo en pdf y después lo muestra

Comment: Y cómo se hace eso? :O jaja. Me interesa saber como se hace para poder mostrarlo. el cómo lo hace, es el fin de mi pregunta jaja

Comment: @FabianMontoya asumiendo que tienes Outlook instalado https://github.com/ichiroc/msg2any

Comment: @RuslanLópez y cómo lo implemento en mi web? ._.  No encontré ejemplo en el repositorio jaja

Comment: puedes jalarlo con exec si usas php, o su equivalente si tu servidor es node, lo mejor sería que lo especificaras

Comment: Es c# (Visual Studio)